# Understanding what is meant by 'Steep' pulse

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider smooth reaction-diffusion systems
$$
u_t=Du_{xx}+f(u;\mu)\qquad (1)
$$
with $u=u(t,x)\in\mathbb{R}^N, D>0$ a diagonal positive diffusion matrix, and $f$ a smooth non-linearity, depending on the parameter $\mu\in\mathbb{R}$.

Traveling-wave solutions $u=u(x-ct)$ solve the traveling-wave equation
$$
u_{\xi}=v,\qquad v_{\xi}=-D^{-1}(cv+f(u;\mu))\qquad (2)
$$
in phase space $(u,v)\in\mathbb{R}^{2N}$, with independent variable $\xi=x-ct$.

In a paper, the following assumption is made:

> > There exists a steep pulse at $\mu=0$ with wave speed $c^*>0$. More precisely, it is assumed that there exists a solution $u_{*}(x-ct)$ to (1) and $\delta >0$ such that
> >     $$
> > e^{\eta\xi}\lvert u_{*}(\xi)\rvert\to 0,\text{ for }\xi\to\infty,\qquad\text{ and }e^{-\eta\xi}\lvert u_{*}(\xi)\rvert\to\infty\text{ for }\xi\to-\infty,\qquad (3)
> > $$
> >     for all $0<\eta<\delta$. In other words, $u_{*}$ is exponentially localized in the front and decays subexponentially in its wake.

To be honest I do not understand what (3) means. The given paraphrase that

> > $u_{*}$ is exponentially localized in the front and decays subexponentially in its wake

is no help for me, unfortunately.

Since $u_{*}$ is supposed to be a pulse, we have that $\lim_{\xi\to-\infty}u_{*}=\lim_{\xi\to\infty}u_{*}(\xi)$. Now I guess that $(3)$ makes some statements about in which way these convergences happen?

**Edit** I would interprete (3) in the following way:

1.) $\xi\to +\infty$:  The pulse solution $u_{*}$ decays *faster* than exponentially since $e^{\eta\xi}\to +\infty$ and hence, if $e^{\eta\xi}\lvert u_{*}(\xi)\rvert\to 0$, we need to have that $\lvert u_{*}(\xi)\rvert\to 0$ faster than $e^{\eta\xi}$ tends to infinity. Maybe this is meant by "exponentially localized"?

2.) $\xi\to -\infty$: Just the other way round, i.e. the solution $u_{*}$ decays *slower* than exponentially. Maybe this is meant by "subexponentially".

Comment: Based on the exceprt that you've provided I would have arrived to the same interpretation. By the way, I don't really know whether it is *this* important how do they call these properties of solutions :) However it would be very interesting how they find and prove that some solution of corresponding travelling wave ODE has this properties.